# Call function/axios function before component died

Tags: reactjs

I would like to know if it's possible to call function before component died.
I tried a lot of things like the code bellow but it's not working as expected.
Like :

```
export const  isOnIOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)|| navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);
export const  eventName = isOnIOS ? "pagehide" : "beforeunload";
```

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    window.addEventListener(eventName, () => {
      this.handleLogOut();
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.handleLogOut();
    window.removeEventListener(eventName, this.handleLogOut);
  }
```

It's almost working on computer but quite weird cause sometimes I haven't log of my axios function; on Iphone/Ipad it's not working at all.
So I would like to know if you guys have others ideas about this ?
Thx a lot and have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no lifecycle hook for component «death». Closest to this action is componentWillUnmount() for class based components and useEffect hook for function based components.

So, if you have

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.handleLogOut();
    window.removeEventListener(eventName, this.handleLogOut);
  }
```

the equivalent code for function based component will be:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    this.handleLogOut();
    window.removeEventListener(eventName, this.handleLogOut);
  }
}, [])
```

Also be sure to check out [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) for more detailed info.

Comment: So that's possible to have logs each time user switch pages or components ?

Comment: @HugoP why can't you log in ComponentDidMount() method?

Comment: ok my english is not very good, but what i mean is I would like to get the time user spend on the specific part of my website. Do you know what i mean ?

Comment: @HugoP now I understand you. I would set initial time in ComponentDidMount() method and then in ComponentWillUnmount() will calculate the difference. 
Try converting your class based component into functional component and use useEffect hook for this, it worked for me. Code from ComponentDidMount() method you should put in useEffect before the return statement.

Comment: okok but I got a lot of refacto and it's quite annoying :/ but you think it's a better solution.

Comment: @HugoP if your class do not contain a lot of logic, it is considered a better practice to use functional components w/ hooks. Hope it helps you.

Comment: ok I gonna try your solution but can you give my screen of code or something like this to help me to test you solution ?

Comment: @HugoP check this out:     useEffect(() => {
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        return () => {
            document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
        };
    }, []);

It works perfectly in my case. When component will be unmounted, the return statement will be executed. When its mounted, code above return will be executed.

Comment: @HugoP so did it help you?

Comment: I'm stil working not it's not working as expected but better than yesterday ;)

Comment: Ok for now it's work! I use Hooks like you told me and working fine without "addEventListener" but I still have some modification on. When I'll have sometime, I'll make a post to explain how I process ;) thx again!

Comment: @HugoP glad in helped you :) Make sure to upvote answer, wish you all the best.

Answer (score 0):

We cant get 100% accurate event that the component "died", the componentWillUnmount() method runs only if the window isn't closed and the component went away from browser "paint".
the "beforeunload" event can help but we can't rely on it
read docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

as well ass this package also can help

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beforeunload

Comment: So that's possible to have logs each time user switch pages or components ?

Comment: yes....and it will be accurate only if user doesn't close the browser